# How do I return a SFML text from function?

Tags: c++, sfml

So i wrote a class for displaying a text in SFML and a function to retur the result so in main I can use `oknoAplikacji.draw(wyjdz_z_gry.wyswietlanie())`, where oknoAplikacji is main window and wyjdz_z_gry is object created with the class I made.

```
sf::Text wyswietlanie(){
        sf::Text napis;
        //here it assigns stuff like what should be written, what font to use etc.
        return napis;
    }
```

However, this doesn't work. I tried to make it into pointer and made it look like this:

```
sf::Text * wyswietlanie(){
        sf::Text napis;
        //stuff that makes napis napis
        return &napis;
    }
```

And then in main loop:
`oknoAplikacji.draw(*wyjdz_z_gry.wyswietlanie());`

This time, it compiles, but immidetly crashes and error message says this:

```
pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception
```

How can I properly return `napis` to use it later?

And also, this is my full code:

```
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

using namespace std;

class Przycisk{
public:
    string nazwa;
    int wymiarx;
    int wymiary;
    int pozycjax;
    int pozycjay;
    
    Przycisk(string nazwa, int wymiarx, int wymiary, int pozycjax, int pozycjay){
        this->nazwa=nazwa;
        this->wymiary =wymiary;
        this->wymiary=wymiary;
        this->pozycjax=pozycjax;
        this->pozycjay=pozycjay;
    }
    
    
    sf::Text * wyswietlanie(){
        sf::Text napis;
        sf::Font czcionka;
        czcionka.loadFromFile("czcionki/arial.ttf");
        napis.setFont(czcionka); 
        napis.setString(this->nazwa);
        napis.setPosition(this->pozycjax, this->pozycjay);
        return &napis;
    }
    
};

int main()
{
    int szerokosc = sf::VideoMode::getDesktopMode().width;
    int wysokosc = sf::VideoMode::getDesktopMode().height;
    sf::RenderWindow oknoAplikacji( sf::VideoMode(szerokosc, wysokosc, 32), "nazwa okna", sf::Style::Default);
    
   
    sf::Texture menu_glowne_tlo;
    menu_glowne_tlo.loadFromFile( "tekstury/menuwersja_na_komputer_szkolny.png" );
    sf::Sprite menu_glowne; 
    menu_glowne.setTexture(menu_glowne_tlo);
    
   
    
    
    Przycisk wyjdz_z_gry("wyjdz z gry", 280, 60, 800, 250);
    
    while( oknoAplikacji.isOpen() )
    {
        sf::Event zdarzenie;
        while( oknoAplikacji.pollEvent( zdarzenie ) )
        {
            if( zdarzenie.type == sf::Event::Closed )
                oknoAplikacji.close();
           
            if( zdarzenie.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && zdarzenie.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape )
                oknoAplikacji.close();
        
            
        }
            oknoAplikacji.draw(menu_glowne);
            oknoAplikacji.draw(*wyjdz_z_gry.wyswietlanie());
            oknoAplikacji.display();
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and sorry for making the variables in polish but it really makes it more readablo for me since i know exactly what is a variable and what is not, since that has to be in english

Comment: `return &napis;` would be a bug. You can't return a pointer to an object that no longer exists. Or at least there is no point in doing so because you can't use the pointer after the function ends.

Comment: No clue why the first attempt didn't work yet, but the second returns a pointer to a local variable. The variable goes out of scope at the end of the function, leaving the pointer dangling. It can't work. You should expand on what went wrong with the first try. If you got compiler diagnostics, copy and paste them into the question. If it ran but did something unexpected, describe what happened and what you expected to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```cpp
    sf::Text * wyswietlanie(){
        sf::Text* napis = new sf::Text();
        sf::Font czcionka;
        czcionka.loadFromFile("czcionki/arial.ttf");
        napis->setFont(czcionka); 
        napis->setString(this->nazwa);
        napis->setPosition(this->pozycjax, this->pozycjay);
        return napis;
    }
```

And then in main loop:

```cpp
            sf::Text* tekst = wyjdz_z_gry.wyswietlanie();
            oknoAplikacji.draw(*tekst);
            delete tekst;
```

You'll need a matching `delete` when you're done with this font if you use this way.

Actually, it would probably be more efficient to load the font once at the beginning of the program than loading it every time a string is rendered. Perhaps consider loading the font once in a different method before calling the method to render a string and then keeping a pointer to it around in `Przycisk`.

Or maybe a `shared_ptr`. The advantage of using smart pointers instead of raw pointers is that you don't need a destructor or copy constructor.

Here's how to do that using shared pointers:

```cpp
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class Przycisk{
public:
    string nazwa;
    int wymiarx;
    int wymiary;
    int pozycjax;
    int pozycjay;
    shared_ptr<sf::Font> czcionka;
    
    Przycisk(string nazwa, int wymiarx, int wymiary, int pozycjax, int pozycjay){
        this->nazwa=nazwa;
        this->wymiary =wymiary;
        this->wymiary=wymiary;
        this->pozycjax=pozycjax;
        this->pozycjay=pozycjay;
        this->czcionka = make_shared<sf::Font>();
        czcionka->loadFromFile("czcionki/arial.ttf");
    }
    
    
    shared_ptr<sf::Text> wyswietlanie(){
        shared_ptr<sf::Text> napis = make_shared<sf::Text>();
        napis->setFont(*czcionka); 
        napis->setString(this->nazwa);
        napis->setPosition(this->pozycjax, this->pozycjay);
        return napis;
    }
    
};

int main()
{
    int szerokosc = sf::VideoMode::getDesktopMode().width;
    int wysokosc = sf::VideoMode::getDesktopMode().height;
    sf::RenderWindow oknoAplikacji( sf::VideoMode(szerokosc, wysokosc, 32), "nazwa okna", sf::Style::Default);
    
   
    sf::Texture menu_glowne_tlo;
    menu_glowne_tlo.loadFromFile( "tekstury/menuwersja_na_komputer_szkolny.png" );
    sf::Sprite menu_glowne; 
    menu_glowne.setTexture(menu_glowne_tlo);
    
   
    
    
    Przycisk wyjdz_z_gry("wyjdz z gry", 280, 60, 800, 250);
    
    while( oknoAplikacji.isOpen() )
    {
        sf::Event zdarzenie;
        while( oknoAplikacji.pollEvent( zdarzenie ) )
        {
            if( zdarzenie.type == sf::Event::Closed )
                oknoAplikacji.close();
           
            if( zdarzenie.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && zdarzenie.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape )
                oknoAplikacji.close();
        
            
        }
            oknoAplikacji.draw(menu_glowne);
            shared_ptr<sf::Text> tekst = wyjdz_z_gry.wyswietlanie();
            oknoAplikacji.draw(*tekst);
            oknoAplikacji.display();
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where I need to put `delete`? It says nothing about it on SFML website (https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/graphics-text.php), and it seems like it's the main issue

Comment: Put the `delete` in your while loop after drawing `tekst` if you used the raw pointer version of wtswietlanie (the one returning `sf::Text*`). However, if you used shared_ptr approach you don't need to `delete` the variable.

Comment: I've tried both of your solutions and the first one gives the same result as my first approach to this problem: the code compiles and runs, but the window immidetly closes and gives return value 3221225477 for some reason. The second one gives me a lot of errors with the first one being `'shared_ptr' does not name a type`, do I need to install something? I've included the same libraries as you did

Comment: [https://james.darpinian.com/decoder/?q=3221225477](https://james.darpinian.com/decoder/?q=3221225477) 3221225477 is an access violation. You will most likely need to use your debugger to figure this out.